# postman return '????' output of arabic name

Tags: php, json, api, postman

Hello I wrote my code in php and i'm trying to show output in arabic name but postman give output
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "msg": "Login Sucessful",
    "driverId": "11",
    "fullName": "??? ???????"
}

but i need to show output in 
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "msg": "Login Sucessful",
    "driverId": "11",
    "fullName": "عبد الرحمٰن"
}

so how can i do this thank you

and also this name ('عبد الرحمٰن') is also stored in database but display in php json output

please co-oprate if i have any spelling and grametical error..

Comment: What version and what platform are you currently using? Could you show an image of the response Headers please.

Comment: @DannyDainton Hello Sir, Thank You For your response . but i solve this problem using JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES. And Thank You Again